# Java: Basic class definition

Tags: java, class, methods

Define the missing method. 
licenseNum is created as: (100000 * customID) + licenseYear. 
Sample output: Dog license: 77702014

This is what I did:

```
 public void createLicenseNum() {
    licenseNum = (licenseNum * 100000) + licenseYear;
    return;
 }
```

But it's incorrect. Where am I going wrong?

> CallDogLicense. java:32:
>    createLicenseNum() in DogLicense cannot be applied      to (int)
>    dog1.createLicenseNum(777);

Code from file DogLicense.java

```
    public class DogLicense {
      private int licenseYear;
      private int licenseNum;

      public void setYear(int yearRegistered) {
        licenseYear = yearRegistered;
        return;
      }

      // FIXME: Write createLicenseNum()

      /* Your solution goes here  */

      public void createLicenseNum() {
        licenseNum = (licenseNum * 100000) + licenseYear;
        return;
      }

      public int getLicenseNum() {
        return licenseNum;
      }
    }
```

Code from file CallDogLicense.java

```
    public class CallDogLicense {
      public static void main (String [] args) {
        DogLicense dog1 = new DogLicense();

        dog1.setYear(2014);
        dog1.createLicenseNum(777);
        System.out.println("Dog license: " + dog1.getLicenseNum());

        return;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You've written a method that accepts no arguments. Your `main` method is trying to call it with the argument `777`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method doesn't have any arguments, it's not javascript. You need to do this:

`public void createLicenseNum(int customId) {...`

Now if you call it like this `dog.createLicenseNum(500);` then inside that method variable named `customId` will have a value `500`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `customID` argument to your method and use it in your calculation:

```
public void createLicenseNum(int customID) {
    licenseNum = (customID * 100000) + licenseYear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your're calling the method with `int`, however it's declared to take no parameters.

```
public void createLicenseNum(int licenseNum) {
  this.licenseNum = (licenseNum * 100000) + licenseYear;
return;
```

Will solve the problem.

Still it's not how we do that in Java. For constructing objects you should use constructor.

```
public class DogLicense {
    private int licenseYear;
    private int licenseNum;

    public void setYear(int yearRegistered) {
      licenseYear = yearRegistered;
      return;
    }


    public DogLicense(int num, int year) {
        licenseNum = (num* 100000) + year;
    }

    public int getLicenseNum() {
        return licenseNum;
    }
}

public class CallDogLicense {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
      DogLicense dog1 = new DogLicense(777, 2014);
      System.out.println("Dog license: " + dog1.getLicenseNum());
      return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KfqQ.png)

Where I went wrong was not declaring int before createLicenseNum(int customID) {

After declaring the customID in the method's parameters, be sure to include that ID in the formula as that integer will be called upon.

Finally, I was error'd because it only typed return; at the end, not return licenseNum;.